# SVN to Production quality code

Tags: svn, production

Hi I have SVN repo that I frequently use for change management.

However after each fix, I have to upload the code to the production server.

At the moment, I upload files by files so that the .svn directory do not uploaded.

Is there a way to upload the all code from svn repo to server without .svn directories, the easier way?

Comment: I am using Windows XP SP2. And Eclipse PDT. The question is resolved btw. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the command is

```
svn export [URL]
```

This exports your svn repository without the .svn meta information. If you want to automatically deploy it to a test/production server you might have a look at the [post-commit hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s02.html).